# How can I hide the text correctly when the mouse leaves an item?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this site:

[link](http://dl.dg-site.com/service-prestations/)

When the user puts hover on the(...) must appear as text.When there is not over the item should disappear text.

I tried to use this code but do not work properly.

There goes right ... unless you bring certain portions of the screen arrow.

**Code JQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".ascunde").hide();

        $('.plus').hover(function(){
           $(".ascunde").show(500);
            $(".plus").hide(500);


       });

        $('.page-id-1675 section .container').hover(function(){
           $(".ascunde").hide(500);
          $(".plus").show(500);


       });
         $('.gigi').click(function(){
            $(".ascunde2").show();
            $(".plus2").hide();
          });

        $('.plus2').hover(function(){
            $(".ascunde2").show(500);
            $(".plus2").hide(500);


       });

        $('.page-id-1675 section .container').hover(function(){
            $(".ascunde2").hide(500);
            $(".plus2").show(500);

       });



});
```

Can you tell me please what is the problem and what is not working properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```
$('.plus').hover(function(){
    $('.plus').hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
},
function(){                  
    $('.plus').show();
    $(this).parent().next().hide();   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wa7ywxL0/2/

Comment: I want to take away the text when the arrow on the blue box.

Comment: Change `$('.plus').hide()` to `$('.plus').css({'visibility':'hidden'})` so it work more effectively and do the same with `$('.plus').show()` to `$('.plus').css({'visibility':'visible'})`

Comment: Yes I know what you say but I want to take away the text when the arrow on the blue box? understand?Thanks!

Comment: @cristi, no i don't really understand. But your HTML is not really needed. Use classes on those T1. T2 (same class like in my example) Classes can be the same. ID's can't! SEE UPDATED ANSWER